# Index and Sumproduct

Tags: excel

I have a working formula to return the last time a client placed a bet, I need to change this to the first time a client placed a bet.

I have a worksheet with 2 pages, first page is the "databank" second page is "time".

I have a working formula to return the last time a client bet on the "time" sheet.

```
=INDEX(Databank!B:B,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(Databank!C:C)*(Time!A8=Databank!C:C))))
```

`Databank!B:B` contains a list of dates
`Databank!C:C` contains a list of client codes
`Time!A8` contains a client code

This formula (placed in `Time!D8`) successfully returns the date the last entry that particular client was seen in the databank.

I would like to change this for the first time a client was entered into the databank, I have tried replacing MAX with MIN but this hasn't worked.  (I am dragging this formula down 500 rows to hopefully return the date the client was first seen).

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Index function will return the value/reference of the given point in the range. All you need to do is to point. Index(Range,row_num,col_num). So Databank!B:B is your range, then you use MATCH function, that looks up the first occurrence of the given value in a range and return its position, and that position will be your row number in Index function. Then you have 0, as I assumed there is only 1 column in the databank range. All together:

```
=INDEX(Databank!B:B,MATCH(Time!A8, Databank!C:C,0),0)
```

Comment: Providing only the code doesn't explain why your answer works. Could you add an explanation?

Comment: Sure! The Index function will return the value/reference of the given point in the range. All you need to do is to point. Index(Range,row_num,col_num). So Databank!B:B is your range, then you use MATCH function, that looks up the first occurrence of the given value in a range and return its position, and that position will be your row number in Index function. Then you have 0, as I assumed there is only 1 columnt in the databank range. @pdpi

Comment: Thanks. Added that into the response proper for easier reading.